# ProgressDialog crashing application

Tags: android, listview, progressdialog

I'm trying to get a ProgressDialog to load my listview before displaying it but i'm getting a crash. Would there be a better way to implement this?

EDIT: Updated with the logcat error, forgotten about it.

```
List<String> internetArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ProgressDialog p;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ListView internetList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

            p = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait..", "Loading list..", true);

            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    //do some extreme work before creating list

                    try {
                        sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    internetArray.clear();
                    //p.dismiss();
                }


            }.start();

            getPermissions(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, internetArray);

            arrayAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {    
                        public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                            return object1.compareTo(object2);
                        };
                    });

            internetList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

}
```

Comment: Forgotten about it, just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Without a logcat from a first glance this is the problem: `p.dismiss();`.

You are trying to dismiss a UI element, in your case the progress dialog from a background thread.

Although I am certain that this is the cause, you should post your logcat for more details.

EDIT: The above error should be taken under consideration, although the error appears in creating the dialog: `MainActivity.this` this can't be instatiated. You can try passing the actual context by `this` and not class context `MainActivity.this`.

```
p = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait..", "Loading list..", true);
```

UPDATE: Perhaps in your line of code is working but you have to know that when you are trying to access a UI element from a background thread would cause memory leaks (you are not even trying to access it through `runOnUIThread()` method, this is serious according to my opinion).

I didn't say that you should not add it at all, but you should add it in the ui thread. To our problem now, did the `this` work? Because I don't see any new logcat or something... :)

Comment: Without the p.dismiss(); the dialog just stays and i am unable to dismiss it no matter what even after the listview is loaded and there's no error in console

Comment: You said that you no longer have any problems. It appears to me that the topic is closed and the `this` worked. So shouldn't my answer be confirmed so that others with the same problem know it worked? That is the main purpose I guess